# Creating a Map for methods and running all of them

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Ive just started developing in scala. I have multiple classes in a scala application.

```
object A {
  def run() = println("Class A")
}
object B {
  def run() = println("Class C")
}
object C {
  def run() = println("class C")
}
```

I want to create a manager class for them so that I can run the required class based on argument passed and run all of them if no argument is passed. Thinking of creating a Map and call functions accordingly. How can I call all the methods in the map?
I want to do something like this.

```
object MainClass extends App{
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val methodMap = Map(
      "A" -> A.run _ ,
      "B" -> B.run _,
      "c" -> C.run _
    )

  }
```

The compiler says
`[error]  found   : String => Unit
[error]  required: () => Unit`

How do i achieve it and also, this implementation looks a bit messy to me. Can you suggest something neater?
Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get this error? As far as I can tell, that shouldn't happen here

Comment: can you post full code & tell us where you got exception ??

Comment: The code looks pretty good as-is and if you do `methodMap("A")()` it will print "Class A." Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What you describing can be implemented via a wrapper class or proxy. It is possible to call method dynamically based on method name and particularly via Scala reflection. Although that would create an unnecessary overhead. So write a wrapper/proxy and in there call all the methods that you need

Comment: what is the relation to Apache Spark here? I don't get it

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, thanks a lot for suggestion. Can you please elaborate on wrapper/proxy class or provide a link that contains the pattern for reference?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn calling the method as suggested by you says `Unspecified value parameters: v1: String`

Comment: See example here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/43DxRqCKSw6D9Z4PKbk9Vg

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```scala
 trait R {
    def run
  }
  object A extends R {
    def run() = println("Class A")
  }
  object B extends R {
    def run() = println("Class B")
  }
  object C extends R {
    def run() = println("class C")
  }
```

### test

```scala
 def runUtil(r: Seq[R] = Seq(A, B, C) ) = r.foreach(_.run)
    println("Run-1")
    runUtil(Seq(A))
    println("Run-2")
    runUtil()
 /**
      * Run-1
      * Class A
      * Run-2
      * Class A
      * Class B
      * class C
      */
```